# Menu drop down not working on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a menu drop-down that works fine on Mozilla and Chrome but on Internet Explorer it doesn't. 
When the drop-down scrolls down and I go with the mouse above it, it hides.

```
<ul>
    <li class="t-item t-state-default" style="float:right;"><a class="t-link" href="#"><img alt="image" class="t-image" src="/Newsletter/Content/Images/icon_logout.png" /> </a></li>
    <li class="t-item myAccount t-state-default"><a class="t-link" href="#Nav-7">Contul meu<span class="t-icon t-arrow-down"></span></a>
        <ul class="t-group">
            <li class="t-item">
                <div class="t-content" id="Nav-7">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Salut </td>
                            <td><em>Username</em></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td> Cont </td>
                            <td><select id="ddlConturi" name="ddlConturi">
                                    <option selected="selected" value="0">Toate</option>
                                    <option value="1">Cont 1</option>
                                    <option value="2">Cont 2</option>
                                </select>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><a href="mylink">Do stuff</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried to fix this using jquery but it didn't work.

```
$(".myAccount table *, .myAccount table *:focus,.myAccount table *:active").hover(function () {

            $(".myAccount ul.t-group").css("display", "block");
        }, function () {
            $(".myAccount ul.t-group").css("display", "block");
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this meta tag in between your  tags:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

It works fine for me. It will force off compatibility view. Fair warning, this is kind of a hack.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could bind to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `hover`. Because when you move mouse to another elements the event get's bubbled up and eventually the drop down hides.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS selector, > (greater than character) is not supported by IE.
You can't use :hover pseudo-elements on anything other than anchor tags, otherwise IE won't read it.

See the the links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html